# TL-WN727N issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

I've bought a TL-WN727N Wireless USB Adapter and I used that on kali, ubuntu 16.04, windows 10, windows 8.1 and it worked properly as it's expected....
but I tried this on ubuntu 14.04 and ubuntu didn't recognize it, My question is why it worked on ubuntu 16.04 and didn't work 14.04 and what should I do to use it on ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this adapter worked on Ubuntu 16.04, then it is supported by Ubuntu 4.4 kernel.

You need to upgrade kernel in Ubuntu 14.04 to get it working, You can do it by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Reboot after you install the kernel.

Comment: Really Thanks, I've been looking for a solution for 2 days